# Updating a Jar in production

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, production-environment

I have a Swing/Java application that is being used for clients and has weekly updates.
The problem is the setup just lay out the classes and their respective directories and on the update I just update the classes.

I want to do a single jar containing all the classes, but I'm not sure how would I be able to update it...

Also some clients need some updates during the week where only one or two classes would be updated.

What is the right way of doing this ?

Im using Eclipse.
EDIT: I know how to create the jar, I just dont know how to dynamically update it.

Comment: I think you should specify what IDE you are using because there are ways to generate jars for each IDE which might be very time saving.

Comment: Using Eclipse, you could right click your project and navigate to: `Export > Runnable Jar > ...` and then fill in the required settings.

Comment: I know how to create the jar, I just dont know how to dynamically update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way of doing this, even if only small changes were made, would be to repackage your JAR after each update and give that JAR to a user. The user would replace the existing JAR. *How* you produce your JAR is up to you. Many IDEs support it, you could write a shell script, use existing build systems like ant or maven or even make, whatever. (See edit below)

If your JAR is very large and deployment is cumbersome, you may be able to split your project into smaller subcomponents, each with their own JAR, and only redistribute the ones containing changes. That may or may not be a major refactoring for you, and it might not even be appropriate. For most small or average size projects, this is generally unnecessary.

As for deployment, there are also a zillion ways to make that easier on the user. You could just give them a JAR file. You could use e.g. install4j. You could use Java Web Start (although its kind of clunky). There are others.

Both install4j and JWS support automatically checking for updates. If you choose to support that feature, all you would need to do is update your distribution site, and users would receive updates automatically. That's also up to you.

But a short answer to your question is: If you have all of your classes packaged in a JAR, no matter how many classes change, you'll want to give the entire updated JAR to the user. The benefit that counters this cost is that a JAR is a nice, compressed, self-contained collection of your application/library's source, which makes management and deployment very convenient.

*Edit:* Responding to your edit where you specify that you are using Eclipse, Josh M gives you instructions in his comment on your answer. To add to his comment, to export a Runnable Jar you'll have to have a Run Configuration set up which, if you've been running your application in Eclipse already, you probably already have. If not you can create one in the Run menu.

*Edit 2:* Please refer to [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238544/616460) as well for some good JWS tips.

Comment: install4j has a way of giving the repackaged JAR (updated) to the client and replacing the old one directly?

Comment: Yes: See http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/autoUpdate.html JWS is arguably easier to set up here, but has a tendency to misbehave. Still, JWS works well more often than not and would be a good drop-in solution if you just want to get this project out the door quickly. If it's not sufficient for you you can always change to something else like install4j later.

Comment: Not directly on-topic: If you're going to start getting serious about updates and deployment, I also recommend using a version control system such as Git or SVN. If you do that, tagging revisions each time you release an update is an effective maintenance strategy, that way you can go back to previous release updates to investigate problems, etc. Both Git and SVN integrate nicely into Eclipse.

Comment: I'm using SVN, and I dont think I can use JWS because theres a database attached to the update, the procedures on the db need to be updated too. I just really wanted to package everything up, instead of serving the entire directory structure to the client wich is what I'm doing right now.

Comment: For databases I like to include a `revisions` table that contains a list of revision numbers, appended each time the database is updated (possibly with a timestamp and a comment). You can then check that table to see what your current database version is (e.g. `order by revision desc limit 1`) and write SQL scripts to programatically perform incremental updates on the database. You could, for example, have your application check and apply its own database updates on startup, or have the installer run the update script (not sure if that's possible with JWS). As usual, there are many options.

Comment: Install4j is a commercial product which must be purchased. This may or may not be important to you.

Comment: Yes, I realized it. Is JWS really stable? I've never heard of any applications in the area that I work using it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it really stable. I've had great success with it in the past, as well as great failures. Check out Getdown: http://code.google.com/p/getdown/ I've never used it, but it was designed out of some frustrations with JWS by a game developer called Three Rings. I only mentioned Three Rings because I've played many of their games extensively in the past and was always impressed, as a user, with their update deployment. I didn't realize it was open source until just now. I remember when they switched from JWS to Getdown years ago, now it all comes full circle, I guess. Looks very easy.

Comment: @JasonC please do not make _undocumented_ claims about the inferiority of a given technology as part of praising another. Especially so for commercial software. Do you have concrete documentation for your claims about Java WebStart?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I thought I was very impartial towards it. I wrote "I've had great success with it in the past, as well as great failures." I even recommended it in my post (and I was your answer's first upvote). Personally, I had bad experiences with it and wouldn't use it, don't let that stop you from using it. I certainly made no claims that it was "inferior" to anything. Additionally, getdown is not commercial software. I am sure you misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you look into Java WebStart which is designed to do exactly what you need.

You need to first create the finished deployment and then you can look into creating a JNLP file for the deployment, and a way to put all the files to a web server for the user to access.  For now just let the user download the whole thing every time you update.  When you get more experienced you can look into how you can make incremental updates.

I would strongly recommend including a build number or timestamp in the deployment paths so a jar file is not cached incorrectly in the client by accident.

Comment: Appreciate your help.